# Talend Add & Subtract in Expression

Tags: talend

Troubleshooting an existing Talend Job in OpenStudio which has some nested calculations in the Expression. One of the columns has this in the expression field.

```
     retrw.AVG_COST.subtract(retrw.AVG_PRICE!=null?retrw.AVG_PRICE:retrw.IPO_PRICE).add(retrw.IPO_CPRICE).subtract(retrw.IPO_DVB!=null?retrw.IPO_DVB:(new BigDecimal(0.0)))
```

I am having trouble translating this to a regular SQL Request/formula. Dont have an error per se but want to know if my translation is correct.

Hoping someone here can validate?

What I think this expression is translated to in SQL is:

```
  AVG_COST - (DECODE(AVG_PRICE,NULL,IPO_PRICE,AVG_PRICE))+ IPO_CPRICE - (DECODE(IPO_DVB,NULL,0.0,IPO_DVB))
```

The lack of parenthesis is throwing me off. Hence the confusion.

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks,
Bee

Comment: its not sql but looks to be java expression. You translation of ? : to decode is correct.

Comment: I don't like decode, how about this: AVG_COST - COALESCE(AVG_PRICE,IPO_PRICE) + IPO_CPRICE - COALESCE(IPO_DVN,0)  Maybe the last coalesce is not required if your choice of database handle  number - null = number